# Is there a way to use IIS windows authentication in react native mobile app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, azure-active-directory, ntlm-authentication

I am working with a project where users are currently being authenticated using IIS server windows authentication. I have been looking a solution to use authentication in mobile side since last 2 days but still could'nt figure it out as I have to use windows authentication I can't go with jwt or any other authentication mechanism.

Comment: In my opinion, the mobile device does not support Windows authentication you could try to use the active directory authentication.https://serverfault.com/questions/721450/windows-authentication-with-iis-and-mobile-devices

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to use your mobile phone for second factor authentication but at the same time, you do not want to use Two Factor authentication solution.

You can try MultiFactor Unlock and configuring trusted signal, see the below [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/feature-multifactor-unlock) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I need to use rest api after bypassing NTLM authentication. I have tried the following code but still find no luck:   fetch('http://535daf12.ngrok.io/SearchOne/api/data/folders', {
        method: 'Get',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: ({
        'Authorization': 'NTLM ' + 'username' + ":" + 'password',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),